# Ajuda com liberação de aplicação escrita no Visual C#

Tags: c#

Acabei de terminar um pequeno projeto. No Visual Studio, escolhi a opção "Release" para compilar e executar. Fiz alguns testes e a aplicação rodou normal.

Um dos processos executados pelo aplicativo demora cerca de uns dez minutos para executar no meu PC. Durante a execução deste processo a interface gráfica fica congelada. Até aí, tudo bem. O processo executa normalmente e a saída é conforme o esperado.

O problema é quando executo o aplicativo diretamente do seu local (pasta "Release"). Quando clico no botão que executa o processo acima referenciado, a interface congela como esperado, mas, se por acaso eu clico com o mouse sobre qualquer parte da interface o programa entra no estado "Não está respondendo" e trava.

O problema só acontece se eu inicio a execução que não seja a partir do Visual Studio.

Alguém sabe como resolvo esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve fazer esse processamento utilizando uma thread.

Assim você deixa a interface "livre", enquanto a thread secundária faz o trabalho pesado. Inclusive com isso você pode colocar uma barra de progresso para mostrar ao usuário que está trabalhando.

Comment: Obrigado por corroborar meu raciocínio. Eu já havia feito isso, mas como o Visual Studio me traiu ao não mostrar que o programa entraria nesse estado, achei melhor deixar o programa com uma única thread, pois não precisaria tratar a interface para tratar eventos durante o processo.